# ExoPlayer does not work in background / sleep mode on a Galaxy S8 / Note8 (Android 9)

Tags: background, exoplayer, standby

I have built a simple APK to play (looping) a sound (loop.ogg, 22 sec) from the assets. But if two of my  devices (Samsung Galaxy S8, Note8, running Android 9) go to background (pressing the Home button) or I turn the screen of (standby, sleep mode), the sound begins to stutter after about 50-60 sec. This does not happen on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 (Android 9), OnePlus 6 (Android 10).

Can anyone provide an APK that plays this loop.ogg (or any other sound file) via ExoPlayer without this issue.
I only want to know if it is basically possible to play a sound with ExoPlayer in standby (after screen is off) mode on each device.

sound file (loop.ogg, 141 KB): https://drive.google.com/file/d/18yYJz1PaA-PkHIqnYiQBXn1knqoqIPFJ/view?usp=sharing

ExoPlayer test APK (6 MB): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y356HYdWpt1q53-IuLMO8hhoMkfkCw-b/view?usp=sharing

See also here: https://community.kodular.io/t/exoplayer-about-10-or-15-minutes-the-application-closes-when-the-screen-turns-off/51653/5?u=bodymindpower

Comment: If I use an uncompressed audio format (WAV file), the problem does not arise. In this case the problem does not occur. So what is the reason why ExoPlayer has this problem in the background / standby (sleep mode) when using a compressed audio format (OGG, MP3, M4A, ...).